# Decrypt AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in NodeJS from ColdFusion encrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption, coldfusion

I'm merging a nodeJS app with a ColdFusion application. I have a encryption being done in ColdFusion using the method below where key is a encrypt key string

```
key = 'nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q=='
encrypt(value, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX");
```

Then, in NodeJS, I am trying to decrypt it using crypto

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = "nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q=="; 
const binaryEncryptionKey = new Buffer( key, "base64" );

decrypt = (value) => {
        try {
            var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( "AES-128-CBC", binaryEncryptionKey );
            var value = (
                decipher.update( value, "base64", "utf8" ) +
                decipher.final( "utf8" )
            );
            return value;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
}
```

It first return a warning for the buffer:

```
DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

Then, I got the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "iv" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
```

I don't have an "iv" because the ColdFusion side did not use it to encrypt. Is it possible to decrypt it in NodeJS?

- When I change to Buffer.alloc, I get the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "size" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q==..)
```

For example, I have the following encrypted string: `FB391CAAE5CD8FF47C55211ED8636D213C95F233B615D4E56CB7CD6B051D01DF356E1C45ED7AABAB5F9BCBB9EED6355B`

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't give us a sample dataset (plaintext, ciphertext and key) so I'm not been able to check any implementation, but as you are using "CBC" as mode there has to been an iv. According to the docs "When ColdFusion creates an IV automatically, it generates a secure, random IV and prepends this to the encrypted data." the first 16 bytes of your ciphertext is the iv - use this value as input for your iv and decrypt the rest.

Comment: @MichaelFehr, sorry about that. I just updated the post to add the key and sample data to be decrypted. I don't know what ciphertext is or should be. Could you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ColdFusion `encrypt` function is described [here](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt). The 16 bytes IV required for AES/CBC can be specified explicitly. If no IV is given, it is automatically generated and placed in front of the ciphertext (s. also Michael Fehr's comment). The decryption in NodeJS can be done as follows:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = Buffer.from('nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q==', 'base64');  
const ivCiphertext = Buffer.from('FB391CAAE5CD8FF47C55211ED8636D213C95F233B615D4E56CB7CD6B051D01DF356E1C45ED7AABAB5F9BCBB9EED6355B', 'hex');
const iv = ivCiphertext.slice(0, 16);
const ciphertext = ivCiphertext.slice(16);

var decrypt = (value) => {
    try {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, iv);
        var value = 
            decipher.update(value, '', 'utf8') +
            decipher.final('utf8');
        return value;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

console.log(decrypt(ciphertext)); // 4388576099656673
```

With the result `4388576099656673`, consistent with the corresponding ColdFusion script, which can be executed e.g. [here](https://cfdocs.org/decrypt), s. *Examples*:

```
<cfscript>
key = 'nQw7y6QejwGFh/SNrul20Q==';
iv = BinaryDecode('FB391CAAE5CD8FF47C55211ED8636D21', 'HEX');
ciphertext = '3C95F233B615D4E56CB7CD6B051D01DF356E1C45ED7AABAB5F9BCBB9EED6355B';
plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext, key, 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding', 'HEX', iv);
writeOutput(plaintext);
</cfscript>
```

Note that [`new Buffer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding) is deprecated. A description of `Buffer.alloc()` can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the explanation